# How to change Tkinter text color

Tags: python, colors, tkinter

I have a pop up window that lets you choose your own color but I get a error when I use it and click ok for it to change the text color.

Here is the code:

```
from tkColorChooser import askcolor

def ColorChange(self):
    Color = askcolor(color="White", title="Color Chooser")
    self.Cont.config(foreground=Color)
```

Comment: You forgot to say what GUI you use - PyQt, PySite, wxPython, Tkinter, HTML

Comment: @furas, It's Tkinter.

Comment: @furas I am using Tkinter

Comment: `print Color` to see what you get.

Comment: @furas That's just the thing I know why its not working I have printed it and it is in rgb not a actual color name. I just can't figure out how to change the text with the color the user chooses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`askcolor` returns a tuple of following form: `((r, g, b), 'color')`.

For example:

```
((0, 0, 64), '#000040')
```

`foreground` option should be a color name or a color color; You need to change following line:

```
Color = askcolor(color="White", title="Color Chooser")
```

with:

```
_, Color = askcolor(color="White", title="Color Chooser")
```

Comment: Thank you you have solved my problem. I was unable to find any solutions on my own or online.

Comment: Is there any way to save the font color to that file when I re open it later?

Comment: @cdw100100, Save the configuration to a file when color is changed. Load the configuration at load time. It deserves another question.